# Is it possible to program HTML input onKeyPress event with javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I´m trying to program html input onkeypress event from javascript but it doesn´t work, but I can program atributes like size or type.

```
var element3 = document.createElement("input");
element3.type = "text"
element3.size = "6"   
element3.onkeypress= "return isNumberKeyDecimal(event)"
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `onkeypress` property accepts a function, not a string.

```
element3.onkeypress = isNumberKeyDecimal;
```

But also take a look at the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) function for the preferred approach to dealing with event listener functions.

In particular, you may wish to look at [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate), which would allow you to have a single event listener on a container element rather than having to bind it to each input you create.

Comment: +1, because +3 is not possible: +1 for `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` for older IE's), +1 for _not_ using a wrapper function, but assigning the handler directly and +1 for suggesting delegation

Answer (score 3):

```
element3.setAttribute("onkeypress", "return isNumberKeyDecimal(event)");
```

Comment: Will that work? Do browsers (other than IE with its global event object) create an `event` variable when you set the attribute as a string?

Answer (score 2):

```
element3.setAttribute("onkeypress", "return isNumberKeyDecimal(event)");
```

[Mozilla reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Answer (score 1):

It should be set as a function not a string.

```
element3.onkeypress = function(event){return isNumberKeyDecimal(event)}
```

Comment: Or, you could write this code as `element3.onkeypress = isNumberKeyDecimal;`